# "we must acknowledge" + "however": what's the right word order?

Tags: word-order

I am trying to figure out what is the best place for the word "however" in the sentence *"We must acknowledge that"*. I've found occurrences of each order on the Internet.
 So I'm wondering which is the most idiomatic wording and if there is a difference (in terms of meaning) between them?

> - **However**, we must acknowledge that...
> - We **however** must acknowledge that...
> - We must **however** acknowledge that...
> - We must, **however**, acknowledge that...
> - We must acknowledge, **however**, that...

Comment: This is a matter of style and emphasis depending what you are trying to communicate.

Comment: Choices 1, 4 and 5 are all okay. They all mean the same thing. Choice 1 would be preferred if there was some reason to draw attention to the contrast right at the beginning of the sentence, but this could depend on a million things. If you said "We, however, must acknowledge..." it would sound as if a contrast was being drawn between "us" and other people, which might sometimes be the intended meaning, but usually not.